How to grey out a modifier panel UI element?
I would like to achieve a greyed-out effect similar to this:

Except in the object modifiers menu:

The parameter can be accessed by bpy.data.objects["My Object"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_23"]

Note in case of an operator it will be greyed out if the operator's poll method returns False in this context

How could this be implemented if I'm dealing with a geometry nodes modifier panel and not a custom made panel?

You cannot override this layout using the python API. You can create a whole new one however.

here is a small example:
import bpy

class SimplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Simple Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_simple_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = 'object'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object

        layout.prop(obj, "enabled_property")
        layout.enabled = obj.enabled_property
        layout.prop(obj, "my_property")



def register():
    bpy.types.Object.enabled_property = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Enable Field", description = "hi", default = True)
    bpy.types.Object.my_property = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="My Property")
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimplePanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimplePanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

so essentially you can use
layout.enabled = ... 

to do that.
